# Tableofcontents revtex4-1

Tags: revtex

I would like to use the `\include` command in a document written with the document class revtex4-1. Unfortunatelly the so inserted `sections` are not displayed in the tableofcontent although they appear in the document. Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

```
\documentclass[preprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\include{Foo}
\include{Bar}
\include{Fooo}
\include{Baar}

\end{document}
```

Where the respective files are stored in the same folder containing the following text.

Foo:
`\chapter{Foo}`
Bar:
`\chapter{Bar}`
Fooo: 
`\chapter{Fooo}`
Baaar: `\chapter{Baaar}`

Comment: Why `\include` and not `\input`?

Comment: Perfect, this solves the problem. I wasn't aware of this comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, look at this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/101651 for more info.