# Incompatibility between RevTeX, \include{}, and \label{}?

Tags: labels, include, revtex

I have a large project that uses the RevTeX documentclass. Sections are incorporated using  \include{}. The problem is that labels are not correctly resolved (Reference `xxx' on page 1 undefined). A strange aspect of the issue is that many (most?) references work, but some do not.

Here is a minimum working example

```
 %\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \documentclass[12pt]{revtex4-1}
 \newcommand{\be}{\begin{eqnarray}}
 \newcommand{\ee}{\end{eqnarray}}
 \begin{document}
 Eq. \ref{test2}
 \be
 \label{test2}
 1+1=2
 \ee
 \include{eos}
 Eq. \ref{test3}
 \be
 \label{test3}
 1+1=2
 \ee
 \end{document}
```

where eos.tex is

```
Eq. \ref{test}
\be
\label{test}
1+1=2
\ee
```

The label in eos.tex is not resolved. The other labels are. The problem can be fixed by replacing \include{} by \input{}, or by not using RevTeX.

Is this a known incompatibility? Or some kind of intended behavior?

Comment: RevTeX does redefine *a lot* of kernel code: I never investigated the reason but the issue already popped out on this site (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357821/82917). Anyway, given that `\include` starts a new page and is thought more for `\chapter`s (which don't exist in `revtex`) I'd say that using `\input` is better. You can always include a manual `\clearpage` if you want.

Comment: unrelated to the question I think but eqnarray is deprecated it is better to use `align` from `amsmath` but if you do use it the there must be two `&` per row one either side of the relation.

Comment: @campa  Thanks. I posted, in part, because I spent many hours yesterday night to reduce the problem to a MWE, and then figure out that \input{} solves the issue. I'm hoping to spare others some of the pain.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. However, `\include` always adds `\clearpage` at the beginning and end, and it's unlikely you really want it.

Comment: @egreg Interesting. I first encountered the issue in overleaf, and thought it might be an overleaf problem, but my own TeX distribution (TexLive/Ubuntu) exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: @egreg Strange, I can. I've tested it also with `revtex4-2`.

Comment: @campa OK, I get the issue with TL 2019 and 2020, but not with TL 2021

Comment: @egreg Er, sometimes I forget that I run TL2017... Interestingly, I can reproduce the problem by using the latest `revtex4-2` with `LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>`. Do you have any idea what change might have fixed the issue?